# JS IF statement by ID

Tags: javascript

I have live chat opening times across my site each with their own ID (data-chat-category). There is one category ID I want to target to give different opening hours to. I'm struggling to write an IF statement to target this ID. I've extracted the JS out that needs to be edited.

Here is the HTML with the ID:

```
<div class="live_chat" data-chat-interface="toms" data-chat-category="407" data-chat-product="370"></div>
```

Here is the parameter:

```
var iChatCategory = $(this).attr('data-chat-category');
```

and this is the bit I can't get right or need to add the IF statetment too:

```
// Show correct opening times for all iChatCategorys except 407
var sOpeningTimes = (sChatInterface.indexOf("toms") >= 0) ? 'Live chat is open Monday to Thursday from 8:30am to 5:30pm, Friday 8:30am to 5pm.' : 'Live chat is open Monday to Friday from 8am to 8pm, Saturday 8am to 6pm.';

// Show correct opening times for iChatCategorys 407 only goes under here?
```

Comment: `if (ichatcategory == 407) { set special hours } else { set standard hours}`?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var sOpeningTimes = "";
 if(iChatCategory !== "407") {
 sOpeningTimes = (sChatInterface.indexOf("toms") >= 0) ? 'Live chat is open Monday to Thursday from 8:30am to 5:30pm, Friday 8:30am to 5pm.' : 'Live chat is open Monday to Friday from 8am to 8pm, Saturday 8am to 6pm.';

 } else {
  sOpeningTimes = "message for iChatCategory 407";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just edit the conditional in the ternary.

```
// Show correct opening times for all iChatCategorys except 407
var sOpeningTimes = (iChatCategory != 407) ? 'Live chat is open Monday to Thursday from 8:30am to 5:30pm, Friday 8:30am to 5pm.' : 'Live chat is open Monday to Friday from 8am to 8pm, Saturday 8am to 6pm.';
```